# In @OneToMany mapping not able to fetch the associated object

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

```
public class Answers {
    private int answerId;

    private String answer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Questions questions;

}     

public class Questions {
    @Id
    private int questionId;

    private String question;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "questions")
    private List<Answers> answer;
}

   Answers answers = session.get(Answers.class, 1234);
   System.out.println(answers.getQuestions());   //giving null pointer exceptiom
```

while fetching answer I'm not getting the question object associated with it. while getting associated question with the answer I'm getting null pointer.

Comment: `answers` must be `null` in `answers.getQuestions()`, are you sure your database has such a `1234` record?

Comment: yes I have entry with the same id in database

Comment: Is the app retrieving it?  Can you disable/temporarily remove the join and see if you get the `answers` object?  I'd also suggest turning on sql logging (refer to hibernate/jpa/whatever you're using docs) and see what SQL it is attempting to run.  The point is that calling `answers.answer` would also throw an NPE so not sure the problem is related to your `@OneToMany`

Comment: Fetching question is giving answers associated with it but if I fetch answer it fetches answer object but the question object is null

Comment: https://github.com/thisIsManu/hibernateDemo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/hibernate/MappingDemo/OneToMany/OneToManyDemo.java